# Linq-asp.net Core- Get the only one row after grouping

Tags: linq

Newbie in linq, it's hard for me to get the really first row after a group by.
It always return the first row of each group.
For example, with my tests data, I get two rows in the result.

But I only want one row. The first one.

At the end of my query, there is :

```
...... select new {RGBCode=Query3.RGBCode} into LastQuery
group LastQuery by LastQuery.RGBCode into grouping
orderby grouping.Count() descending 
select grouping.First()
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: do you have to rows are the same ``RGBCode`` and after grouping you want to get the first? it's not clear, i think if you add some data and the expected result to help us understanding the problem.

Comment: my sql server data table has, to simplify (cause I have to make several cascading join) two fields : id and rgbcode. Mysample data have these rows : id=2 / rgbcode=#F5FF10 + id=2 / rgbcode=#F5FF10 + id=2 / rgbcode=#F5FF10 + id=2 / rgbcode=#9B59b6 + id=2 / rgbcode=#9B59b6. So, I have 5 rows, all rows with id=2, 3 rows rgbcode "#F5FF10" and 2 rows rgbcode "#9B59b6". And I just want to get "#F5FF10" as result. Thank you for your message

Comment: Try using this at the end of your code.
select grouping.Take(1).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm considering your test based in comment, and i have created test collection like:

```
List<RgbTest> rgbs = new List<RgbTest>
{
    new RgbTest{Id=2,Code="#F5FF10"},
    new RgbTest{Id=2,Code="#F5FF10"},
    new RgbTest{Id=2,Code="#F5FF10"},
    new RgbTest{Id=2,Code="#9B59b6"},
    new RgbTest{Id=2,Code="#9B59b6"},
};
```

you can get the data by 2 ways:

```
string rgbTestCode = rgbs.GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Code })
    .OrderByDescending(y => y.Count())
    .FirstOrDefault()
    .FirstOrDefault()
    ?.Code;
```

Or

```
string rgbCode = (from a in rgbs
                  group a by a.Code into groupedRgb
                  orderby groupedRgb.Count() descending
                  select groupedRgb.FirstOrDefault())
                  .FirstOrDefault()
                  ?.Code;
```

**Result**

```
#F5FF10
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: @Negatonrax can you check my answer, it's work just fine for me.

Comment: My god, it works ! Than you so much. Didn't figure to make to cascading "FirstOrDefault" at all ... Thank you agin !

Answer (score 0):

When you group something in LINQ the result is an `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>`
when you take first, its `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` Where `TKey` is a group key, some particular `RGBCode` in your case and `TElement` are actual objects that have common `TKey`

```
var list = new List<A>
{
  new A{SomeProp = 1 },
  new A{SomeProp = 2 },
  new A{SomeProp = 2 },
  new A{SomeProp = 1 },
  new A{SomeProp = 2 },
};

 IEnumerable<IGrouping<Int32, A>> grouped = list.GroupBy(a => a.SomeProp); // Here the grouping is going on;
 IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<int, A>> ordered = grouped.OrderBy(group => group.Count()); // Ordered groups; 
 IGrouping<Int32, A> first = ordered.First(); // First Group, Note the type is "IGrouping<Int32, A>";
 Console.WriteLine($"The key group is: {first.Key}");
 Console.WriteLine("Group Values are:");
 first.ToList().ForEach(a => Console.WriteLine(a.SomeProp)); // First Group actual elements are enumearated and SomeProp property is printed;

 Output: 
 //The key group is: 1
 //Group Values are:
 //1
 //1
```

So basiccaly if I wanted to show first `SomeProp` from the first group I would have to do this:`first.First().SomeProp` - `Output: 1`

Comment: Thank you so much to have spend this time to explain in details. I guess i'm doing something wrong because when I change my last line of the query above from "select grouping.First()" to "select gr.First().RGBCode", I still have two rows returned. For information, linqpad let appears that my object type is, in my case, a IOrderedQueryable<string>

Comment: I think it does not matter at this point in time because Sajid already answered your question, but I think `gr.First().First().RGBCode` is what you were looking for.